# About many to many parent child relationship

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm having trouble with the table structure

I want to make 2 parent child table that are connected

The illlustration is

[image: Table in excel]

The first table is a category table, where it will be the first parent child table
The second table is a rule table, where it will be the second parent child table

This table should be connected with 'many to many' on the last child

Code 01.01.007.04 should be connected with the category code 5.2.2.34.01

I've tried the looping in laravel code but it can't be same with the table in the excel

The following is an overview of my table in mysql

```
#Tabel category
- category_id
- category_code
- category_name 
- parent_id

# Tabel rule 
-rule_id
-rule_code
-rule_name 
-parent_id

#table refund
- refund_id
- category_id
- rule_id 
- month_refund
- refund_amount
```

Comment: If you need a many to many then you need a join table, that table would need an ID that would be attached to your third model: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: No, its not. it more complex problem